# meaning of a phrase

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am reading a novel. I faced the expression **hand to god** and I don't know the meaning.

The paragraph is:

> Jack's daddy was a sheriff, his granddaddy was sheriff, and **hand to god**, his grandma too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the previous question:  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297694/the-meaning-of-the-phrase-hand-to-god

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a way of swearing to the truth of what one is saying. Variations include:

> I swear to God
>
> God be my witness
>
> I swear on the Bible
>
> By all that is Holy
>
> God's truth
>
> Right hand to God
>
> Hand on my heart
>
> etc.